# How to click on the Cookie numerous times in-order to play cookie clicker within https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I was trying to make a simple selenium program to play cookie clicker from what I have seen I can't figure why it is not working here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

cookie = driver.find_elements_by_id('bigCookie')
cookie_count = driver.find_elements_by_id('cookies')
items = [driver.find_elements_by_id('productPrice' + str(i)) for i in range (1,-1,-1)]

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(cookie)

for i in range(5000):
    actions.perform()
```

and here is the error I was getting

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ffl_s/Desktop/Botting/My Bot/cookie.py", line 15, in <module>
    actions.click(cookie)
  File "C:\Users\ffl_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 102, in click
    self.move_to_element(on_element)
  File "C:\Users\ffl_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 273, in move_to_element
    self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element)
  File "C:\Users\ffl_s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\pointer_actions.py", line 42, in move_to
    raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement
PS C:\Users\ffl_s\Desktop\Botting\My Bot> [21704:18120:0918/223803.402:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [22:38:03.402] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

Comment: Hi there what seems to be the problem?

Comment: When I try to run the code it opens up the correct website but nothing happens after that

Comment: Have a try at this actionchains one.

Comment: yes had the same issue

Comment: Did you delete the rest of the code>

Comment: Look up chrome driver manager for the second error it seem your binaries are messed up.

Comment: Sorry but would it be possible for you to explain a little further on what you just said to do I'm still new to this and don't completely follow what you're saying

Comment: The setup for selenium is incorrect. You can simply pip install using command prompt. Chrome driver managers makes sure your using the right driver for the chrome version you are using. If you just install that and do the bottom your problem should be solved.

Comment: I added the code you put and in terminal I put "pip install webdriver_manager" and it is still not working

Comment: must not matter said I already had it when I put that

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is maybe your Chome Version because the code works on mine.

Comment: my chrome version is 85.0.4183.102 pretty sure I downloaded the right version driver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click 5000 times and display the cookies text you could do this.
Just pip install webdriver-manager to fix up your binaries as well.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
for i in range(5000):
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('bigCookie')).click().perform()
items = driver.find_element_by_id('cookies')
print(items.text)
```

Comment: Just remove the rest and use this.

Comment: that's what I tried and it is still failing when I try to run it

Comment: where would I send that won't let me in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **Cookie** numerous times inorder to play [**cookie clicker**](https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
  for i in range(100):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bigCookie"))))
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#cookies").text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  80 cookies
  per second : 0
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: CookieClicker]